# Can you use a while loop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, while-loop

Problem : I am trying to create an array of 4 things from a list but the while loop always produces an infinite loop.

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

const getThings = () => {
     while(options.length < 4) {
          let randomThing = 
listOfThings[Math.floor(Math.random()*listOfThings.length)];

     !options.includes(randomThing) && setOptions([...options, randomThing]);
    }
};
```

I believe the problem is connected to another issue - when I call the function once, it is randomly called anywhere between 2 - 9 times even without the while loop attached. Still trying to figure out why it keeps randomly firing so much.

```
getThings();
```

Answer (score 4):

`setState` does not instantly change any values. Create the entire array first, then set the state at the end of the loop.

```js
const getThings = () => {
    let newOptions = [...options];
    while (newOptions.length < 4) {
        let randomThing = listOfThings[Math.floor(Math.random()*listOfThings.length)];
        if (!newOptions.includes(randomThing)) newOptions.push(randomThing);
    }
    setOptions(newOptions);
};
```

Comment: This is a **constantly-repeated** duplicate question. It doesn't need Yet Another Answer.

Comment: Thanks @Unmitigated, this is still producing an infinite loop for me though.

Comment: @BryanF Then perhaps you do not have enough items in your array to produce 4 unique ones within a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because you are calling setOptions inside a loop, you could cache a new output in the function and then call the hook at the end

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level